# Wrapping interpolation with quotes

Tags: ruby, loops, interpolation, quotes

```
range_array = (0..100).to_a
range_array.each do |number|
  p %-<div class="#{number}"><h1>Dell Shitbox</h1></div>-
end
```

Result:

```
"<div class=\"83\"><h1>Dell Shitbox</h1></div>"
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="83"><h1>Dell Shitbox</h1></div>
```

I have tried escaping:

```
range_array = (0..100).to_a
range_array.each do |class|
  p %-<div class=\"#{class}\"><h1>Dell Shitbox</h1></div>-
end
```

I have tried switching the quoting method (many, many times)

```
range_array = (0..100).to_a
range_array.each do |class|
  p %Q[<div class="#{class}"><h1>Dell Shitbox</h1></div>]
end
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Is your code throwing an error? It appears to be acting as it should.

Comment: +1 Though for a very well formed question. You presented current code, expected result, and included what you have tried. I think you are a little confused on what the code is doing but you have a well formed question.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell The problem is that the code is outputting a backslash (and outer double quotes). I read somewhere that the backslash doesn't exist, which I can fathom, but unfortunately HTML can't. Suggested docs?

Comment: @Anthony No it won't unfortunately

Comment: check out the pickaxe, http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ under Standard Types and then under the header Strings

Comment: Are you trying to write this to a `.html` file or are you using a template system like erb?

Comment: Oh the problem is he's using `p` instead of `puts`. It outputs completely fine, but he's calling `inspect` on it with `p` and therefore everything is escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because you are outputting the string using `p`. `p` is the same as calling:

```
puts object.inspect
```

The simple fix is to use `puts` instead of `p`.